# jQuery YouTube first video by default

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a bunch of videos that changes when the link was clicked. All works fine except one thing. I want the first video to be displayed when the page loads. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/J4rV3/

```
<!-- Youtube Video Player --> 
<div id="yt_container"></div>       
<!-- End of YT Video Player -->

<div class="related"> 
<h5>Related Videos</h5>
<div id="yt_videos">
        <a href="yTe-wSkRlbQ"><i class="icon-video"></i> Install</a>
        <a href="uZ9Xt6x2kS8"><i class="icon-video"></i> Authorize</a>
        <a href="IAfw07yLfKY"><i class="icon-video"></i> Get Books</a>             
        <a href="kdCXVCjB_Jw"><i class="icon-video"></i> Download</a>              
        <a href="9oDzQOvFS4k"><i class="icon-video"></i> Read</a>              
        <a href="NYLoJPYPBeI"><i class="icon-video"></i> Listen</a>            
        <a href="g4xMBd74hFw"><i class="icon-video"></i> Return</a>            
        <a href="OTdjzSW3jSE"><i class="icon-video"></i> Playbook Tips</a>     
</div>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {     

       $('#yt_videos a').click( function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); 
            var URL = $(this).attr('href');
            var htm = '<iframe width="100%" height="377" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/' + URL + '?rel=0&wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>';
            $('#yt_container').html(htm);       

            return false;
        });     

});
</script>
```

Comment: could this help you ? http://api.jquery.com/first/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work for sure!

```
$("#yt_videos a:eq(0)").trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are searching for is this small script:

```
$(function() {
    var firstVideo = $("#yt_videos a:first-child");
    firstVideo.click();
});
```

You see a working demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/J4rV3/1/

This triggers the `click` event on the first `<a>` tag inside your `#yt_videos` container.

Answer (score 1):

> Try this: Use eq in Jquery to get what ever element in the dom element.

```
 $("#yt_videos a:eq(0)").trigger('click');
```

Comment: why this would be a bad answer?